# Can Dock setting be set up to show/open applications on second screen?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-dock

I have dock set up to show on both monitors. But whenever I click the show applications button or launch something from the dock on the second monitor it lists applications or opens them on the primary monitor.

I would for dock that if application is opened on 2nd monitor that it will open on second monitor

Is there any way to set up dock that applications are shown or opened on whatever monitor the dock is used on?

Answer (score 2):

Install the Gnome Shell extension "[Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/)". It allows to display all Gnome Shell controls on multiple monitors, and hence will allow you to open Activities or Applications on any of the monitors where you click the relevant control. The extension allows you to configure what you want to duplicate on the additional monitors and what not.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium , that works on the applications. Actually had it installed but never used it. Only thing when I click the show application button (the 9 dots button) on second monitor it still goes back to the first monitor. Couldn't see anything on the extension setting that deals with that.

Comment: Sorry to hear the extension does not help to have the program overview display on the current screen.