# Show Applications on screen 1

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

When I click on *Show Applications* at the bottom of the Dock, it always opens on screen 1, despite the fact that the Dock has been placed on screen 2 (which is on the left).

Any suggestions on how to configure this behaviour?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1118989/739431

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same issue and solved it by using the [Dash to Panel extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel).

The *Show Applications* panel with the applications appears on the active screen/monitor.